# Can identifierForVendor be same for two iOS device installed the same app by using iTunes restore back up?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, itunes-app

I have used **identifierForVendor** to uniquely identify a Device for one of my app, I am fetching this value on app launch and storing it into keychain by setting keychain property **thisDeviceOnly**. Now I am having issues, the identifierForVendor returning same vendor id when I tried installing it from itunes back up.

Steps I am doing:

- I have two iPads say iPad1 and iPad2.
- iPad1 has app installed say X already and iPad2 is a new device.
- I have take taken backup of iPad1 on iTunes.
- Now I restored iPad2 from the iPad1 back up using iTunes
- I launched the X app on iPad2 and getting the vendor id same as iPad1
  app X.

did any one obsorved this issue or its something else? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because the keychain is shared on iCloud so any new device, synchronised with your iCloud account will automatically get the keychain.

Comment: I am setting keychain property kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly then how is it getting copied.